# Error caused by the internal android SDK

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, internal

I'm having a problem, when I try to debug my mobile android app. This Error occures ***ONLY*** when I try to debug my app, which makes debugging impossible.
Maybe usefull info: I am using Android Studio 2.1.3

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mFragmentManager' on a null object reference
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:414)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:409)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:99)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:943)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1091)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2888)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18563)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2248)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1306)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1548)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6642)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Edit:
**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId (MyAppID)
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'

    //Google
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'

    //Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: add `app/build.gradle`. If possible code of Activity, you may had done something wrong with fragmentManager

Comment: @piotrek1543 Added the app/build.gradle file content

Comment: update your build-tools from `23` to `24`. Do the same with Support libary, as it may be Google's libs bug

Comment: I would rather avoid doing so. I can't update my android Sdk, because my sdk manager is playing crazy. It worked just fine before, so I don't think the mistake is there